# Delete item from ng-repeat which has a transition animation

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, transition

I have an array of items in `ng-repeat`.
This parent element also has a background-transition animation with 1 second duration.

When ever I delete the element using `splice`, it takes 1 second to remove from the UI. (Based on what time I give for Transition duration)

I don't want to add another class to remove the transition first, and then delete. Or is that the only way?

```
<div class="MyTransitionClass" ng-repeat="d in myArray">     
    {{d.Value}}
    <button type="button" class="CloseIcon" ng-click="DeleteItem($index)">DELETE</button>
</div>

.MyTransitionClass {
    transition: background-color ease-in 1s;
    -webkit-transition: background-color ease-in 1s;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate

```
.MyTransitionClass.ng-enter {
    transition: background-color ease-in 1s;
    -webkit-transition: background-color ease-in 1s;
}
```

Working `jsfiddle` http://jsfiddle.net/irhabi/3fgtqwgq/

Comment: This is a good solution. But I should have mentioned, I am also changing the background when status of the item changes, therefore, not just on ng-enter. So I think in my case this would be more appropriate. .MyTransitionClass.ng-leave {
    transition: none;
    -webkit-transition: none;
}

Thanks.